# Using class as a special value?

Tags: python, class

Is it ugly in Python to use class as a special value?

Consider this:

```
def find_result():
    result = None
    # do something to find the result, even recursing
    return result

r = find_result()
if r is None:
     raise Exception("we have no result")
```

This works perfectly if I expect results to be numeric, or any "normal" type.

But what if there is an arbitrary data structure, and the result can be anything from `None` to another structure?  What I did in my case was something like:

```
class NoResult:
    """i'm even less than `None`."""
    pass

def query(data, path):
    result = NoResult
    # traverse and recurse into the data structure
    return result

r = query()
if r is NoResult:
     raise Exception("our hands are empty")
```

It works, but I can't shake the feeling that I'm a little bit abusing the poor class here, and there might even be a real danger lurking inside.

Is it true?  Am I abusing the class?  Or it's just that my algorithm sucks if it needs rely on a "special `None`" like this?

Comment: Why don't you just raise the exception in `find_result` instead of returning anything? The whole idea of raising an exception is to provide an alternate error detection mechanism that is independent of recognizing a special return value.

Comment: @chepner I did it like that because I needed to recurse deeper, and I never knew that I want to stop searching until returning to the top call.  Now that I think about it, maybe with proper exception handling, it could be better...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called a sentinel, and you can use any unique object for it:

```
sentinel = object()

if r is sentinel:
    raise Exception(..)
```

Here I used a simple `object()` instance instead of a custom class.

A custom class does have the advantage that it is perhaps more self-documenting; if your API *has* to pass the object to users of the API (which can be code), then an explicit class is better. For use just in the black box of the API, `object()` is just fine.

You may want to consider just raising the exception at the point where you now return the sentinel. You can always *catch* the exception again.

Comment: @AloisMahdal: Yeah; I can see that that was confusing. Altered the sentence slightly.

Comment: I've just played with my old code a little and found another advantage of using the class directly (i.e. neither instance of it or a generic object): when you print it, it's `mymodule.NoResult` rather than `<object object at 0x12345>` (Python 2.7).  It's completely free (no `__str__`s needed, just `class X: pass`) and far more readable, especially if you want to use multiple sentinels.  So even if you don't plan on printing it, it's still nicer for debugging and in case it does sneak out, at least it can send the user/you to the right place.

Comment: That's the 'self documenting' part I mentioned. :-)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `result = NoResult()`, and `if isinstance('r', NoResult)?  That is, using an instance of the class, rather than the class itself, as the sentinel.

Comment: @hpaulj: What advantage does that give you? `NoResult` is a singleton, and that's all you need. There is no state to track.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add another approach to what Martijn suggested, is to use the exceptions mechanism to let `find_result` throw a "No Result" exception in the first place and then let the caller decide what to do with it.

```
def find_result():
    result = None
    if (...):
        raise NoResultException("details")
    return result

try:
    r = find_result()
except NoResultException:
     raise Exception("we have no result")
```